# How can I get true north heading in safari ios browser from a sensor-orientation API?

Tags: javascript, ios, augmented-reality, sensors

I was able to get the north heading for Chrome Android using the [AbsoluteOrientationSensor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbsoluteOrientationSensor) API but its doesn't have support for Safari.
Is there any other API or workaround for this.
If not, Does anyone know if there are plans from apple to cover this in the future or a place to ask when would be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, check the [webkitCompassHeading](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/deviceorientationevent/1804777-webkitcompassheading) property from the [DeviceOrientationEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/SafariDOMAdditions/Reference/DeviceOrientationEventClassRef/DeviceOrientationEvent/DeviceOrientationEvent.html)

Comment: Do you know if it's ready to use it on production. In [link] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent#:~:text=DeviceOrientationEvent.webkitCompassHeading) `Mdn-docs` webkitCompassHeading  attribute appears with an icon saying that is 'Non-standar', which i dont know what it actually means.

Comment: It just means you need to be aware of browser compatibility, which you can see in the table at the bottom of the page. As you will see, the browser you were looking for is covered which is Safari on iOS.